# How to make pure js cycle of callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have an API from which I need to query N pages of data. Because I do not want to overload the API, I want to do it sequentially and without blocking the main thread.

The code would be something like this:

```
var res = []; // all data from api
var totalPages = 10;
var pageSize = 100;
for (let page = 0; page < totalPages; page++) {
    // load using jQuery ajax request
    $.get('api.php', { page: page, page_size: pageSize }, function(result) {
        res.push(...result); // add data to resulting array
    });
}
```

But this approach has a few issues:

1. Since it is async, it will just run all requests in parallel, overloading API as a result. I need them to still run async, but each should run only when the previous is done.
2. Since all the calls are async, by the end of the cycle we still wouldn't have the requested data - it will be loading in the background. We need somehow to wait for all callbacks to be done before returning `res` to some other code that needs it.
3. There is no way to make every callback pass its result to the next callback and it is the only way to stop loading when some callback receives "stop loading"/"no more data" request from the server

Is there a way to fix these issues without using some side libraries or promises? Just plain old vanilla javascript.
Sorry if something looks unclear, I am not very experienced in js

Comment: Implement a queue. Also, Promises are great when compared to callbacks, there's no reason not to use them.

Comment: Why do you need all that data at once? You should implement pagination

Comment: @ChrisG could you please post an example of such a queue? As for promises, can I be sure that at least 99% of users have browsers that support them?

Comment: @proofzy even if I use it right in the result callback, that wouldn't change anything in my question.

Comment: Promises *are* plain vanilla javascript.

Comment: @Bergi per https://caniuse.com/async-functions it seems that there are more than 1% of active users that don't support promises, including 0.45% chrome, 0.5% IE and 0.37% edge

Comment: @maxpovver If you want to use only features that more than 1% of used browsers support, then write what you mean and not "vanilla javascript" (which just means js without libraries). However, you already use jQuery so that's not vanilla anyway. And jQuery brings a promise implementation with it! It's not a proper polyfill, but it's still usable. You definitely should use promises here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple recursion here, like this:

```
var res = []; // all data from api
var totalPages = 10;
var pageSize = 100;

const loader = page => {
    // load using jQuery ajax request
    $.get('api.php', { page: page, page_size: pageSize }, function(result) {
        res.push(...result); // add data to resulting array
        if (page < totalPages)
          loader(++page)
        else
          console.log('DONE!');
    });
}

loader(0);
```

Comment: Could improve the answer by also showing how to do this using a promisified `get()` which could then be used inside an `async` for loop and `awaiting` the requests sequentially. But yeah, this is the classic old-school way of doing this which is sometimes useful in more complicated code that promises can't handle well

Comment: @slebetman The requirement was `without using promises`, so `async/await` are out. But you can write your own answer if you consider that it will be useful.

Comment: thanks @syduki! that's what I needed. It would be great to also see promises version @slebetman

Comment: If I write my own answer it would just include a full copy/paste of your answer as the first part of it. It would be better to just avoid that and add it here